# Perl Regex - extracting ipv4 from maillog

Tags: regex, perl, ipv4

I'm working on a distributed fail2ban like system in perl/mysql/iptables.

Extracting ipv4 addresses from /var/log/messages is working, but now
I want to add /var/log/maillog to the soup.

I have a perl regex:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
/ (?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?)\.
  (?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?)\.
  (?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?)\.
  (?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?) /x
```

And a line from maillog:

```
v817YjcU016645: 194.102.60.190.host.ifxnetworks.com [190.60.102.194] did not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA
```

Here the regex matches both `194.102.60.190`.host.ifxnetworks.com
and [`190.60.102.194`]

In my code I have ($IP is the above regex):

```
if ($line =~ m/($IP)/)
{
    my ($ip) = $1;
```

Here the first matching ip-like string is found `194.102.60.190`.host.ifxnetworks.com

So, how do I get the regex to ignore an ipv4 that ends in a `.`

---

<sup>[1]</sup> for readability Perl supports the [/x option](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/194975/readable-regular-expressions-without-losing-their-power/194999#194999)

Comment: Did you try the negative lookahead?  like `/...(?!\.)/`

Comment: I think dots after IP addresses are just a starting point to the problem

Comment: @zdim Yes. Matches `194.102.60.19`0.host.ifxnetworks.com

Comment: I split your regex over lines for readability.  Please check.  If it's OK ... are all four indeed the same?

Comment: @zdim Yes. They are the same `my ($IP) = $OCT . '\.' . $OCT . '\.' . $OCT . '\.' . $OCT` :)

Comment: Thank you.  The problem is the optional digit in the last one.  So whatever you follow it with it has the freedom to just match one less digit, and then that following non-`.` character can be the last digit itself.

Comment: I added a reference for the x option, I hope it's okay for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's the only problem try with the [negative lookahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind)

```
my ($ip) = $line =~ /($IP)(?![.\d])/;
```

which works for the shown data.

The character class in the lookahead, `[.\d]`, is needed because the last term in the `$IP` regex allows for a variable number of digits, via `\d?`.  So with `(?!\.)` alone the engine can match one fewer digits than there are and then that remaining digit satisfies the non-`.` restriction.<sup>†</sup>

Thus we need to disallow both the `.` and a digit following the pattern.

---

A complete program

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $t = 'a 194.102.60.190.host.ifxnetworks.com [190.60.102.194] b';

my $n = qr/(?:25[012345]|2[0-4]\d|1?\d\d?)/;

my $IP = qr/$n\.$n\.$n\.$n/;

my @m = $t =~ /($IP)(?![.\d])/g;

print "@m\n";
```

prints `190.60.102.194`

---

<sup>†</sup> Consider the substring `90.host`. The pattern `/\d\d?(?!\.)/` for it works as follows.

The first `\d` matches `9`.  But the next one, `\d?`, is optional (non-greedy) and it *does not match* if the rest of the pattern can then match. Indeed, `(?!\.)` sees the following `0` to be not a `.` and so we match `9` and `0` satisfies `(?!\.)`. The whole pattern (wrongly) matches

```
perl -wE'$_ = q(90.host); @m = /(\d)(\d?)(?!\.)(.)/; say for @m'
```

prints

```
9

0
```

The middle capture group caught nothing and the next character `(.)` is the `0`.

Now consider the pattern `/\d\d?(?![.\d])/` for the same substring. The `(?![.\d])` requires that what follows is neither the `.` *nor* a digit. Thus the optional `\d?` is forced to match the next digit, `0`. Since the next character then *is* a `.` the pattern fails.

With `(?![.\d])` in the above one-liner test instead of `(?!\.)` nothing is printed, as the pattern doesn't match at all.  (In some shells you may have to escape `!`, so `(?\![.\d])`, or use a script.)

The engine may well not go *exactly* as described, this is more of a loose description of its operation.

Comment: @MogensTrasherDK   Updated the answer with a complete program

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `__DATA__` here to better separate input and program?

Comment: @Wolf Well, when there is a bit of data and we want a completely self-contained program, for an easy demo (no input files to talk about etc). Here it's just one line that is given and it's clearer to simply have it there (rather than read data etc).

Comment: I avoided negative lookahead so far (without a special reason). Are there some performance aspects I should keep in mind when using it?

Comment: @Wolf  Nothing extreme for sure, and I think not anything other to notice either.  There are performance killers with regex, and those one should watch for.  So if a lookhead gets into a backtracking game (for instance), it's not about it but about the structure of the regex, allowing it.  It's just a type of an anchor (non-consuming assertion).

Comment: @zdim Your code works perfectly. I will not pretend to understand the mechanics, but I'm happy anyways. Thanks.

Comment: @MogensTrasherDK I've added an explanation, I hope it helps.  This is a little tricky but interesting, and an example of regex operation.

Comment: @zdim It does help, a little. It would take me too long time to learn something like this. But then again. Now the reference is here, for everybody to find. Again. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In general, regular expressions match on wanted patterns in existing character sequences, it's always a bit harder to not-match if something unwanted exists.

You can match IP addresses<sup>[1]</sup> that are followed by a non-dot (`[^.]`):

```
(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}[^.]
```

and IP addresses at the end of the line (`$`):

```
(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}$
```

you may combine the two patterns by alteration (`|`) in a not-capturing group (`(?:`...`)`):

```
(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}(?:[^.]|$)
```

A similar problem may be that your next task could be to exclude IP addresses that have a dot before them, another problem is that it would also match `2.3.4.5` in `1.2.3.4.5`, which leads back to my introductory statement...

I think that the IP addresses you try to match are best found with something that checks the surrounding characters as well. Be specific about this. For the development stage, try to check non-matching lines by matching them to "garbage patterns". In the case shown in the question (where spaces and brackets are acceptable surroundings), I'd suggest to use

```
(?:[ \[]|^)((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})(?:[ \]]|$)
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> I use a simplified regex here, that also matches `333.333.333.333` or `000.000.000.000`, it can be of course be improved to restrict matches to valid IP addresses, but solutions for this are [abundant](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+ip+address).

Comment: I think the solution is to do the extraction in 2 steps. First: `my ($line1) = $line =~ /(\[)($IP)(\])/;` which matches the `[190.60.102.194]` . Second: `my ($ip) = $line =~ /($IP)/;` which matches the `190.60.102.194`

Comment: @MogensTrasherDK two stages are not necessary in my opinion, see my last additions. The actual match (`((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})`) is already contained in the last ("suggested") regex.

Comment: @MogensTrasherDK Just a reminder: if you (maybe soon) encounter other disturbing interactions between IP addresses and their textual context in some log file, come back and see if you are able to *positively specify* these patterns.